# How can I dynamically fill a ComboBox with XAML in WPF with the values of a List?

Tags: wpf, list, xaml, combobox

In a CSV file I have some string values separated by ';' and some lists (values separated by ','). After reading the CSV I want to display the list as a combobox. 
How can I achieve this using WPF/XAML?

I tried this:

```
<ComboBoxItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Name="DetailParams" Text="{Binding Path=DetailParams, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

...but this generates a combobox item '(Collection)' (in German: '(Sammlung')

To be more precisely:
The ComboBox shall be displayed in a DataGrid's column for each row, whereby each row shows an entity of a class *XYZ*. 
The values of the ComboBox do come from somewhere else but **not** from *XYZ*. Anyway: The selected values of the ComboBox shall be finally stored in a property of *XYZ* (and when the DataGrid/ComboBox is shown, the items shall be preselected in the ComboBox).

```
MainWindow.cs:
private List<string> _tagNames = new List<string>();
public IList<string> TagNames { get { return _tagNames; } }

<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="NotificationsCollectionViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
    <lb:StringListConverter x:Key="StringListConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid x:Name="notificationsGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource NotificationsCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" IsReadOnly="False" 
SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag name" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=TagName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="NId" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Nid}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="IsActive" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsActive}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="detailsParamColumn" Header="Edit">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TagNames, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}">
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

StringListConverter.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace ConfigTool.DataBinding
{
    public class StringListConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.ToString().Split(',').ToList();
        }

        object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            List<string> items = value as List<string>;
            for( int i=0; i<items.Count; i++ )
            {
                sb.Append(items[i].Trim());
                if( i<items.Count-1 )
                {
                    sb.Append(",");
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Because I want to write back the selected values to the CSV file:
Should the Binding Mode be *TwoWay*?

**UPDATE:**

In the DataGrid for the notifications I want to have a ComboBox with **all possible values** for a tag name. These tag names are in a List<string> in my MainWindow.cs but this **list** (named *_tagNames*) is neither part of the NotificationViewSource nor the underlying Notification class. A notification may have one or more tag names assigned but in the ComboBox **ALL possible** tag names (from property *_tagNames*) shall be shown and able to select. ...and the list of selected items shall be written back later on. 
Because *_tagNames* is just a List of strings I can't set something like *Binding Path=whatever*...

**UPDATE (2018-12-14) :**

Once more (because maybe my English is not so good that I have explaned good enough what ny intentiin is ;-) ): I have a class Notification

```
pulic class Notification
{
    public List<string> _mySelectedTagNames { get; set; }
}
```

And in the MainWindow.cs:

```
public partial cass MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<string> _tagNames; // initialized with maybe 100 tagNames (all possible values from which a subset (or even all) can be selected and hence stored in `Notification.mySelectedTagnames`)
}
```

`MainWindow._tagNames` shall be displayed in a ComboBox which is shown in one column of each row.
The user may select zero, on or more items and these selected items shall be stored in the rows underlying Notification class.

Comment: Set the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` to the list of strings? `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DetailParams, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}" />`

Comment: I believe TagNames must be Property of String `public string TagNames { get { return "A;B;C;D,E,F;G,I"; } }` is my understanding correct ?

Comment: No. TagNames is a list of string (maybe 100 of them) containing all possible values. One row in the grid shall display an object which has a property which is a list of strings holding 0..TagNames.length items of list TagNames.

Answer (score 0):

Set (or bind) the `ItemsSource` property of the `ComboBox` to the list of strings:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DetailParams, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}" />
```

This should give you a `ComboBox` with an item per entry in the list returned by the converter.

If you want to display the items next to each other in a horizontal `StackPanel`, you could use an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DetailParams, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Run Text=" " />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```